# How to create textfields in scrollview inside of a tableview IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to create multiple textfield in scrollview that is inside of a prototype cell

[image]

Scrollview and all other elements has different tags

When user clicks add another file , it should generate two empty textfields with labels in above scrollview. Scrollview is in prototype cell.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could present the topics in sections instead of single cells:

- Topic name, time and presenter in the the section header view
- A cell for each of the Files
- The "Add Another
  File" button can be placed in the footer view of the section